# Refresh controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way to refresh a controller in Angular? Consider the following example:

```
<div ng-controller="MsgCtrl" ng-repeat="m in messages">{{m}}<br></div>
<script>
var ws = new WebSocket(something, something);
function MsgCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.messages = [];
    ws.onmessage = function(e) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.messages.push(e.data);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

If the websocket connection fails, or has to be restarted for some reason, a new websocket must be created and listened to. Is there any way to force the controller to run again, creating a new listening function to push the new connection's messages into $scope?

Also, as a secondary question: is there a good place to go to learn more about Angular? The documentation on the site seems a little unclear.

Comment: learn more about Angular : http://egghead.io

Comment: Second egghead.io also http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2446-Using-Controllers-In-Directives-In-AngularJS.htm and http://www.yearofmoo.com/ also http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY lots of other stuff on youtube.  There's an O'Reilly book but it was immediately out-dated.  Also check out yeoman and angular-seed, even if you don't use them they're good for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web socket need to be reconnected when connection failed or need to be restart for some reseason. I think that you shouldn't restart the web sockect
by "restarting the controller".

My suggestion is that create a "web socket" service that will maintain its own logic (e.g., reconnect socket when connection failed) and controller just handle the model and view binding.

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
....
<div ng-controller="MsgCtrl" ng-repeat="m in messages">{{m}}<br></div>
</html>
<script>

    var myApp = angular.module("MyApp",[]);
    myApp.factory("WebSocket",function(){
        var ws;
        var triedTime=0;
        var maxRetryTime=20;
        return {
            createWS: function(server,protocol,handler){
                ws = new WebSocket(server, protocol);
                ws.onmessage = handler;
                ws.onerror = function(e){
                    this.restartWS(server,protocol,handler);
                }
            },
            closeWS: function(){
                if(ws) ws.close();
            },
            restartWS: function(server,protocol,handler){
                if(triedTime<=maxRetryTime){
                    this.closeWS();
                    this.createWS(server,protocol);
                    triedTime++;
                }
            }
        };
    });

    function MsgCtrl($scope, WebSocket){
        $scope.messages = [];

        WebSocket.createWS("something","something",$scope.msgHandler);

        $scope.msgHandler = function(e){
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                //model update
                $scope.messages.push(e.data);

                var msg = JSON.parse(e.data);

                switch(msg.cmd)
                {
                    case "restart":
                    WebSocket.restartWS("something","something",$scope.msgHandler);
                    break;
                }
            });
        }

    }
</script>
```

In the above example, web socket will be reconnected when socket client received the "restart" message or connection is failed. Hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. One of solutions is trying to reload the page using `$route.reload()`. A better solution is try to reinit the websocket on the [`onerror`](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html).
2. I find the best place to learn angularJS is [Egghead](http://www.egghead.io). And stackoverflow is always the best place to ask question if things are not clear for you.